# unescaped value within input element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

could please someone tell me why 'disable-output-escaping' attribute takes no effect in the following piece of XSL template?

```
<INPUT type="text">
  <xsl:attribute name="value" >
    <xsl:value-of select="$query"  disable-output-escaping = "yes" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</INPUT>
```

I would like to see an unescaped value within the 'input' element.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why 'disable-output-escaping' attribute takes no effect in the
>   following piece of XSL template?
>
> ```
>   <xsl:attribute name="value" >
>     <xsl:value-of select="$query"  disable-output-escaping = "yes"
> ```
>
> />

**[D-O-E](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#disable-output-escaping) has effect only for text nodes -- not for attributes**.

If the output method is `xml`, then an XSLT processor must output a well-formed XML document and then it is mandatory to escape special characters in any attribute value.

**You may try specifying**:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

**However, bear in mind that D-O-E is not a mandatory feature of XSLT at all** and some XSLT processors don't implement D-O-E. Therefore, you may need to enter the wanted value manually (and maybe use the "text" output method).

Answer (score 0):

You can change output method to html, i.e.:

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this as a hack to the situation.  By creating a text node and then putting your html there, up until the attribute you need escaped. The document will escape properly.

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping>&lt;input type="text" SIZE="62" name="text1" value="</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="$temp" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping>" /></xsl:text>
```

[Where I discovered the hack...](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2243#comment-12373150)